# removing buttons/links in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an apps and I am making used of django admin, but my apps does not allow deleting of data and django admin have a `delete` button/link. I have already removed the `delete action`.

my question is, how can i remove the `delete` button/link in admin page in django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not remove or change anything in the admin.

Instead remove user's/group's permission to delete given model. If user does not have the permission to delete, the delete button won't appear at any page related to that model.

Answer (score 9):

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MyAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

If the delete permission is not given the "Delete" button of a single object will disappear. The changelist "action" (select list to apply to objects with checkbox checked) will still be shown because you may have the permission to delete some of the objects. You can remove both with the above code.

CLARIFICATION (for the downvoters): admin checks if the current user has the permission to delete and then shows/hides the button/s accordingly. You wrote "my apps does not allow deleting" so I assumed you took away permissions. A superuser does not get looked up in permissions, superuser always returns "yes I have that permission". If you want the buttons to disappear for superusers, you have to use my above code. For other users just take away the permission as per Secator's answer.

Comment: I think the clarification provides the use case for this; despite best practices in all their glory (no sarcasm intended), too many of my clients end up with full superuser access, so in some realistic circumstances this is the best way to stop people from breaking things.

Comment: There are also situations where you might be running an app that you didn't write and was coded to require the user to be superusers, in which case best practices advice does you no good.